# Nuxt 3, Pinia update bodyClass based on state of boolean

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

Is it possible to dynamically update body class based on store boolean value from Pinia store? I'm able to get the value working on page load but it is not updating when I switch routes.

**store:**

```
export const useActiveStore = defineStore({
  id: 'active-store',
  state: () => {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    };
  },
  getters: {
    getID(e: any) {
      return this.isActive;
    },
  },
});
```

**component:**

```
import { useActiveStore } from '~/store/isActive';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
const isActiveStore = useActiveStore();

const { isActive } = storeToRefs(isActiveStore);


useHead({
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: `${isActive.value ? 'isActive' : 'isNotActive'}`,
  },
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't your ternary be using `isActive`?  That is the state variable of your store.  You seem to be using the actual store itself, `isActiveStore.value`, which I don't think is correct syntax either (`.value` is for refs, which the store is not).

Comment: typo on my end. Using storeToRefs I believe .value is correct but I could be wrong

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `useHead` but it sounds like it only sets the attributes for as long as the component setting those attributes is mounted and alive.  Changing routes, and unmounting this component, reverts everything back to normal.  If this body class should always exist, try putting this code in your app's root component, outside the effects of any route changes.

Comment: Have you tried using a computed property to make the whole useHead argument reactive ? Or watch maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `hydrate` function in your store: https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/composables.html#SSR

Comment: How does hydration help when the issue occurs during operation of the app, ie after page load.